# Quantifying sentiment analysis using python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I've been using NLTK in python for doing sentiment analysis, it only has positive, neutral and negative class, what if we want to do sentiment analysis and having a number to show how much a sentence can be negative or positive. Sort of seeing it as a regression problem. Is there any pre-trained library out there to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of a few ways to do this:

- **Vader** returns score as a gradation (between zero and one)
- **Stanford NLP** returns a categorical classification (i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3).

## An NLTK way:

```
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer as sia
sentences = ['This is the worst lunch I ever had!',
             'This is the best lunch I have ever had!!',
             'I don\'t like this lunch.',
             'I eat food for lunch.',
             'Red is a color.',
             'A really bad, horrible book, the plot was .']

hal = sia()
for sentence in sentences:
    print(sentence)
    ps = hal.polarity_scores(sentence)
    for k in sorted(ps):
        print('\t{}: {:>1.4}'.format(k, ps[k]), end='  ')
    print()
```

Example output:

```
This is the worst lunch I ever had!
    compound: -0.6588   neg: 0.423      neu: 0.577      pos: 0.0
```

## A Stanford-NLP, Python way:

(Note that this way requires you to start an instance of the CoreNLP server to run e.g.: `java -mx1g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000 -timeout 15000`)

```
from pycorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP
stanford = StanfordCoreNLP('http://localhost:9000')

for sentence in sentences:
    print(sentence)
    result = stanford.annotate(sentence,
                               properties={
                                'annotators': 'sentiment',
                                'outputFormat': 'json',
                                'timeout': '5000'
                               })
    for s in result['sentences']:
        score = (s['sentimentValue'], s['sentiment'])
    print(f'\tScore: {score[0]}, Value: {score[1]}')
```

Example output:

```
This is the worst lunch I ever had!
    Score: 0, Value: Verynegative
```